# List all Level 2 pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking at adding a two methods of navigation for a website. The first is to have all top level pages to be across the top, I have this working correctly. The issue is that I am looking at adding a sidebar with all sub-pages as a list. I cannot find a method to gather only sub-pages and all search results show how to work with sub-pages of a current page.

The list needs to show all pages regardless of what the current page is and not show any top level pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
$subs = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ));
while( $subs->have_post() ) : $subs->the_post();

    if($post->post_parent == '') continue; // This will skip top-level pages 

    //the code for showing data goes here.

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the depth level in argument in wp queries

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'depth'        => 2,
        'posts_per_page' => -1

);
```

and then pass the argument to query

```
$subs = new WP_Query($args);
```